# phpmyadmin - ORDER by `time` DESC

Tags: php

While I was trying to make a table from MySQL data on my website, I got on one problem. The query I did was 
`$sql = $handle->getAll("SELECT * FROM time ORDER BY time DESC");`

Once I did print_R($sql), the rows weren't in order like they supposed to be

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (

            [uid] => lN48VSi96/Y1S/kJ1BD4lzuPkSE=
            [time] => 6000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [uid] => x11I6rhIOvFyoIhUI/G0cdaTtLA=
            [time] => 5400
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [uid] => x11I6rhIOvFyoIhUI/G0cdaTtLA=
            [time] => 5400
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [uid] => /HC0zRz2vpEbZQ04IWmak2xOl9M=
            [time] => 3000

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [uid] => m+oYRkVqJ4kOboMNK3B1lLM+U+I=
            [time] => 111300
        )

)
```

which is very weird because if it's descending, number 4 should be at the top, number 0 should be 1, number 1 should be number 2, and so on, but it's not like that. Anyone has any ideas why is it like that?

Comment: What is the data type of that column?

Comment: time is varchar(16).

Comment: use `timestamp` or `integer`.

Comment: I just switched it to integer and it worked perfectly fine.. Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome!!!!!!!!!

Comment: If it's a `varchar` column then the order is correct.
'6' is the highest value. '1' is the lowest value.

Comment: @PatrykCz. If your datatype if `VARCHAR` or string, then output is correct. It is sorted `lexically` . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order .